# Border radius em tabela com border collapse

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.item1, .item2, .item3 {
  border-top:1pt solid black;
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
.item1 {
  border-left:1pt solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.item3 {
  border-right:1pt solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>I</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>K</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>X</td>
    <td class="item1">A</td>
    <td class="item2">B</td>
    <td class="item3">C</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>I</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>K</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Resultado obtido:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado desejado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que minha tabela usa `border-collapse: collapse` o que tem impedido de deixar as bordas arredondadas com `border radius`. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `border-spacing:0` ao invés de `border-collapse: collapse`.

```css
table {
  border-spacing:0;
}

.item1, .item2, .item3 {
  border-top:1pt solid black;
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
.item1 {
  border-left:1pt solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.item3 {
  border-right:1pt solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>I</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>K</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>X</td>
    <td class="item1">A</td>
    <td class="item2">B</td>
    <td class="item3">C</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>I</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>K</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```